# after upgrading flutter, I'm always get "Unblock-file" not recognized. how to get rid of these

Tags: flutter, upgrade

I tried to upgrade my flutter from 1.12.13 hotfix 7 stable to 1.12.13.hotfix 8 stable, by running `flutter upgrade` on my windows 7 64 bit machine

now, everytime I run "flutter run", "flutter pub get", etc it runs so slow and sometimes stuck. and I always get some warnings like 'Unblock-file' is not recognized, and "flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer". It also shows "Checking SDK Version...", "building flutter tool..." and "running flutter upgrade..."

Comment: I'm having the same problem now, were you able to fix this?

Comment: @Jevison7x no, I ended up going back to previous version

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Windows Powershell version, also make sure you have the correct paths of git and flutter in PATH from environment variables.
After checking that you have your Powershell higher than 5.0 and the paths, run the Windows PowerShell as an administrator